# ¿Cómo establecer el border-radius desde javascript?

Tags: javascript

Quiero establecer el `border-radius` de un `div` utilizando JavaScript, este script (ver abajo) lo que hace es cambiar de color un div de 500x500 cada vez que se actualiza el `DOM`:

```
function show_pattern(){
    var top_position = 25, left_position = 25; 
    var width = 500, height = 500;
    var color_list = ["red","orange","yellow","green","blue","indigo","violet"];
    var the_body = document.getElementById("theBody");
    var border_radius = 20;

    while(width > 50) {
        var this_div = document.createElement("div");
        var random_color = Math.random() * 7;

        random_color = Math.floor(random_color);
        this_div.style.top = top_position + "px";
        this_div.style.left = left_position + "px";
        this_div.style.width = width + "px";
        this_div.style.height = height + "px";    
        //  this_div.border-radius = border_radius + "px";
        this_div.style.background = color_list[random_color];
        the_body.appendChild(this_div);
        top_position += 10; left_position += 10;
        width -= 20; height -= 20; border_radius -=20;
    }
}
```

He comentado la sentencia errónea para que se pueda ver el punto en el que me he quedado y lo que quiero realizar.

¿Cómo se escribiría bien esto? `this_div.border-radius = border_radius + "px";`

Lo he puesto en un `JS Bin` por si se entiende mejor: [Color script](http://jsbin.com/haqiki/edit?html,js,output)

```js
function show_pattern() {
  var top_position = 25,
    left_position = 25;
  var width = 500,
    height = 500;
  var color_list = ["red", "orange", "yellow", "green", "blue", "indigo", "violet"];
  var the_body = document.getElementById("theBody");
  var border_radius = 20;

  while (width > 50) {
    var this_div = document.createElement("div");
    var random_color = Math.random() * 7;

    random_color = Math.floor(random_color);
    this_div.style.top = top_position + "px";
    this_div.style.left = left_position + "px";
    this_div.style.width = width + "px";
    this_div.style.height = height + "px";
    // this_div.border-radius = border_radius + "px";
    this_div.style.background = color_list[random_color];
    the_body.appendChild(this_div);
    top_position += 10;
    left_position += 10;
    width -= 20;
    height -= 20;
    border_radius -= 20;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="3">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>JS color script</title>
  <style>
    div {
      position: absolute;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body id="theBody" onload="show_pattern()">
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: @rnrneverdies Gracias por las mejoras ... ; he editado un poco más intentando seguir la labor de comprensión.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debes usar [`element.style.borderRadius`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_style_borderradius.asp)

```
this_div.style.borderRadius = border_radius + "px";
```

Aquí te dejo el ejemplo funcionando como creo que quieres:

Ademas hice este cambio, establecí el `borderRadius` al 50% para que se formen los círculos.

```js
function show_pattern() {
  var top_position = 25,
    left_position = 25;
  var width = 500,
    height = 500;
  var color_list = ["red", "orange", "yellow", "green", "blue", "indigo", "violet"];
  var the_body = document.getElementById("theBody");

  while (width > 50) {
    var this_div = document.createElement("div");

    var random_color = Math.random() * 7;
    random_color = Math.floor(random_color);
    this_div.style.background = color_list[random_color];
    this_div.style.top = top_position + "px";
    this_div.style.left = left_position + "px";
    this_div.style.width = width + "px";
    this_div.style.height = height + "px";    
    this_div.style.borderRadius = "50%";
    the_body.appendChild(this_div);
    top_position += 10;
    left_position += 10;
    width -= 20;
    height -= 20;
    
  }
}

show_pattern()
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>JS color script</title>
  <style>
    div {
      position: fixed;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body id="theBody" onload="show_pattern()">
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Ok, ya lo tengo, si lo que quiero es un círculo sería algo así como: `var border_radius = 50; this_div.style.borderRadius = border_radius + "%";`